Is removal of an edge from any Hamiltonian-connected graph still result in a Hamiltonian graph?
Denote by $G-e$ the graph obtained from $G$ by removing an edge $e$. Today,I suddenly thought of a  question:
Is there a Hamiltonian-connected graph $G$ such that $G-e$ is not Hamiltonian where $e$ is an edge of $G$?
Maybe we can find an example or prove that $G-e$ where $e$ is any one edge of $G$  is always Hamiltonian.
I know of a paper that presents a Hamiltonian-connected graph where the removal of any edge results in a non-Hamiltonian-connected graph[1]. However, I am unsure whether my question has already been studied.
[1] X. Zhan, The maximum degree of a minimally hamiltonian-connected graph, Discrete Mathematics, 345(2022) 113159.

So Hamiltonian graph for you means there exists a Hamiltonian cycle, right? Then any cycle graph is an example where you go from Hamiltonian to non-Hamiltonian by removing an edge. So I am a little unsure what you mean in the question : Do you want an example of a graph that preserves Hamiltonicity even after removing any edge?

@HackR A cycle graph is Hamiltonian, but not Hamiltonian-conected.

Ah! I thought it just means Hamiltonian and connected. I stand corected, thank you @MishaLavrov

You haven’t specified which edge’s removal you are interested in. Are you asking, “Does every Hamilton-connected graph have some edge such that…” or “Is it the case for every edge of every Hamilton-connected graph that…”? Or some third thing?

Sorry. I write it not clearly.

Here is a counterexample I found in Mathematica (where it goes by the noble name GraphData[{"Cubic", {12, 81}}]):

Mathematica says that GraphData[{"Cubic", {12, 81}},"HamiltonConnected"] is True, but HamiltonianGraphQ[GraphData[{"Cubic", {12, 81}}]~EdgeDelete~{8<->12}] is False.
Altogether, after checking around 2500 of the 4322 Hamiltonian-connected graphs that Mathematica knows, I found 18 counterexamples. Their Mathematica names are
{"Cubic", {12, 81}}, {"Cubic", {12, 84}}, {"Cubic", {14, 342}}, 
{"Cubic", {14, 382}}, {"Cubic", {14, 384}}, {"Cubic", {14, 386}}, 
{"Cubic", {14, 397}}, {"Cubic", {14, 456}}, {"Cubic", {14, 475}}, 
{"Cubic", {14, 493}}, {"Cubic", {14, 495}}, {"Cubic", {16, 15}}, 
{"CubicPolyhedral", 15}, {"Cubic", {18, 5}}, {"CubicPolyhedral", 34},
{"Cubic", {24, 2}}, {"IGraph", {12, 2, 3}}, {"Fullerene", {40, 26}}

and they are all $3$-regular graphs. (I am excluding $K_2$ and $K_3$, which are too small to exhibit any reasonable behavior.)

(Also, a trivial example is $K_3$.)

Yes. So  is there an example with high connectivity?  For example,4-connected or general $k$-connected. Now this is another question.

@licheng None of the small-ish ones Mathematica knows are $4$-connected, because all the examples I found are $3$-regular! (I'm not sure that specific condition is required, because there's also selection bias: Mathematica just knows a lot of cubic graphs.)

I suspected  that such graphs have minimum degree three.
